# Quota selection in Forsta Beacon Decipher

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to select 2 options in a quota selection out of about 10 choices they can qualify for. My issue is, I have certain options that can not be selected together.

I have this code below, but it will only keep 2 concepts from being selected together. I have 10 concepts and I need to choose from the first 5 or the second 5.

```
C1 = '/Concept Quota/Concept1'
C6 = '/Concept Quota/Concept6'

def quota_hook(sheet, table, cells):
 if sheet == 'Concept Quota':
  assignedCell = False
  for eachCell in cells:
   if eachCell[2] in (C1,C6):
    if assignedCell:
     cells.remove(eachCell)
     break
    else:
     assignedCell = True
 return cells
```

Comment: Your Q seems to be about a spreadsheet manipulation. You should add this info to your Q. Further, your Q might not be replicable as is. You might need to reformat your Q or provide a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Please share a reproducible part of code.